# Traceback (most recent call last): File "python", line 8, in <module> socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, errno

I'm just a beginner in python, so I might not get some things. I'm coding in https://repl.it with python 3.6.1. It runs on Linux.

### I'm making a simple chat program. My server code looks like this:

```
import socket
import sys
import time
## end of imports ###

### init ###
s = socket.socket()
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8080
s.bind((host,port))
print("")
print(" Server done binding to host and port successfully")
print("")
print("Server is waiting for incoming connections")
print("")
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print(addr, " Has connected to the server and is now online ...")
print("")
while 1:
    message = input(str(">> "))
    message = message.encode()
    conn.send(message)
    print("message has been sent...")
    print("")
    incoming_message = conn.recv(1024)
    incoming_message = incoming_message.decode()
    print(" Client : ", incoming_message)
    print("")
```

## It runs just perfectly. This is the code for the client:

```
import socket
import sys
import time

s = socket.socket()
host = "e85717147a08"
port = 8080
s.connect((host , port))
print(" Connected to chat server")
    while 1:
    incoming_message = s.recv(1024)
    incoming_message = incoming_message.decode()
    print(" Server : ", incoming_message)
    print("")
    message = input(str(">> "))
    message = message.encode()
    s.send(message)
    print("message has been sent...")
    print("")
```

## And here, I run into the problem. The console gives me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 8, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

## Thank you guys!

Comment: What is "e85717147a08"?

Comment: The problem seems to be with your host name. I am not sure whether that is supposed to be some MAC address or what,  but that is not how it is working.  Either use the DNS name of the host or a proper IP address of the form:192.168.3.11

Comment: The host that is in there is the one I've got whenever I typed                                          
    host = socket.gethostname()                                                                                      
    print(host)